# Migration from ext3 to Mogilefs

Tags: ext3, distributed-filesystems, migration, mogilefs

I have gigs of images on ext3 file system and I want to move them to Mogilefs on a live running site. In your opinion what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would test and document this in my lab first but the gist would be

- Schedule some downtime and ahead of that

  - create my Mogilefs and mount it.
  - copy the data onto it. and repeat as required to keep it up to date.
- During the downtime (in single user mode)

  - unmount the current filesystem and the Mogilefs
  - mount the Mogilefs  where the original fs was
  - bring the system back on line.
- Verify system was working

Comment: Thank you for suggestion lian. I have my testing servers and I will test it there first.